# Dividers don't fade in and out

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a menu which by clicking on one of its elements, a divider fades in or out. 
https://jsfiddle.net/uLjgyamw/1/

However the code for the fade in and out is giving me trouble when creating a div first and a class inner-container. Any way to solve it?

jQuery:

```
$(document).on('click','#item1', function()
{ 
    $("#container").fadeOut(1000, function(){
        $(".inner-container").hide();
        $("#first").show();
        $("#container").fadeIn(1000);
    });    
});
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific on what exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: You have no `inner-container` class in your HTML.

Comment: @JanR I'm using a slider from imageslidermaker.com (I didn't know how to present it in the JSFIDDLE), now what's happening everything is working fine, but when the window is full-size, the slider doesn't work unless i remove the id first and class inner-container, but this stops my fade in and fade-out option.. I don't know if you could help me with such low info, if not maybe you can tell me how to present the imageslidermaker in a jsfiddle so i can go in more details about my problem.

Comment: @EternalHour i know that's the case, also i don't have a div first, what can i use in replacement of both to make the fade in/out function work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use toggle. it will solve your problem or if you want animation on toggle then use toggleClass. and apply your effect in class and then toggleclass will animate

example: https://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/uLjgyamw/2/

and in first click you want to show #first then on load hide #first so when you click it will be shown.

```
$("#container").css('display', 'none');
$('[id^=item]').click(function () {
    $("#container").toggle(1000, function () {
        $(".inner-container").toggle();
        $("#first").toggle();
    });

});
```

Comment: the problem is that i want the dividers to be hidden at first and fade in if i click on the first element AAAA, and fade out if i click on another element, can it be done with this function you provided?

Comment: @mikebrand  dividers means that gray boxes ? if yes then it is possible

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/uLjgyamw/5/ i think you want something like this if you want some more modification then let me know will help you  :D

Comment: man it's great but how to make it fade out if i click on another element?

Comment: in your code you are using #item1 so it will only work on AAAAA element wait i will update my fiddle it will work on all element like aaa, bb, cc etc ..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81935/discussion-between-keval-bhatt-and-mikebrand).

Answer (score 0):

try to do like this:

```
html($("#container")).fadeIn(1000);
```